# Working on a React project and getting error on TS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am working on a react project and I am new to TS.

Below is my code -

```
interface GetAllRolesResponse {
  id: number;
  roleName: string;
  description: string;
  permission: {
    id: number;
    component: string;
    createPermission: boolean;
    viewPermission: boolean;
    updatePermission: boolean;
    deletePermission: boolean;
  }[];
}

const [rows, setRows] = useState<GetAllRolesResponse[]>(INITIAL_DATA);
```

And INITIAL_DATA looks like this -

```
"INITIAL_DATA": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "roleName": "Client Admin",
        "description": "This is a client admin",
        "permission": [{
            "id": 1,
            "component": "Client",
            "createPermission": true,
            "viewPermission": true,
            "updatePermission": true,
            "deletePermission": true
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "roleName": "Annotator",
        "description": "This is Annotator",
        "permission": [{
            "id": 1,
            "component": "Client",
            "createPermission": true,
            "viewPermission": true,
            "updatePermission": true,
            "deletePermission": true
        }]
    },
]
```

I am setting my setRows like this -

```
const roles = useSelector(allRoles);

useEffect(() => {
    setRows(roles);
    setLoader(false);
  }, []);
```

I am getting a TS error here -
[image]

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your state as an **array** of `GetAllRolesResponse`, but you're trying to update it to be just one instance of `GetAllRolesResponse`

If you want to replace the state with the value returned from `useSelector(allRoles)`, you should make sure that returns an array.

If you want to update the state to add the return of `useSelector(allRoles)`, try this instead:

```js
const roles = useSelector(allRoles);

useEffect(() => {
    setRows((r) => [...r, roles]);
    setLoader(false);
  }, []);
```

Here you'd be creating a new array (never mutate state) with whatever was already in it (`...r`) plus the new roles.

Comment: It is still showing me that error.

Comment: Then I suggest you update your answer to include a reproducible example of your code, preferably using a snippet/codepen.